# what is that mean reinterpret_cast<char *&>(a) = cp;

Tags: c++, casting

Yes this is not very portable, I wonder why one would want to do something like this:`

```
char *cp ;
reinterpret_cast<char *&>(a) = cp;
```

` and what it means?

Thx

Comment: @Jared: Probably `char*`, or this wouldn't work.

Comment: The type doesn't matter though I updated the example.

Comment: @Gman, it's reinterpret_cast, it can do anything, it doesn't have to work persay :)

Comment: @Jared: Well `a` could be anything, but `cp` must be convertible to `char*`. :)

Comment: @STingRaySC: The rhs of the assignment must be convertible to a `char*`, or else the assignment (not the cast) would not compile. `a` can be just about anything, that is granted.

Comment: I would be more interested in the original type of `a` than the type of `cp`, after all `cp` must be convertible to `char*`, but there is no info on what `a` is, which could help in determining any possible sense the cast could have.

Comment: @David: Ok, I see that.  What does it mean that the cast is to a `*&` instead of a `*`?  Would this allow one to "re-seat" a reference?

Comment: @StingRay: No, look at the actual code. `cp` *must* be convertible to a `char*` to be assigned to the result of the cast. The reason it is `*&` is because without the reference, the cast results in an rvalue. (A copy of `a`, treated as a `char*`) By casting it to a `char*&`, it treats `a` itself as a `char*`.

Comment: @STingRaySC: No, the fact that it is casting to a `*&` means that the memory is to be interpreted as lvalue char pointer, and thus can be assigned a pointer to a char.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is casted to a `char*&`. It is called `reinterpret_cast` because the bits are reinterpreted in exactly the fashion requested by the cast target type. The compiler does not check for validity (nor would he be able to). This brings a pointer back to its origins: it's just an address of a piece of memory.

The reason `a` is casted to a reference to a pointer is that a reference is needed to have a valid lvalue to assign `cp` to. `reinterpret_cast<char *>(a) = cp` would have been illegal because you can't assign to a temporary.

It looks a bit ugly in source code. This one:

```
char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(a);
c = cp;
```

is probably better to maintain and read, although it's longer (note it's not exactly the same meaning because we're introducing an extra variable `c` to hold the result of the cast. In the original sample, `a`'s memory is reused to point to the new location `cp`).

Comment: That would probably not have the same meaning. In the question's code, the value of `a` changes to point to, while in your code the value of `a` remains unchanged. The way to make the code easier to read and keep the meaning is actually casting to the pointer type of `a` (assume that `a` is `T*`): `a = reinterpret_cast<T*>(cp);`. Casting in the RHS does not require a lvalue reference, a simple rvalue suffices and thus the `&` can be taken away.

Comment: You're right, my snippet was mis-formed. Edited it just a bit to suit to my explanation. Yours is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are confused about the reference in the cast. Without the reference, we would have something like this:

```
T a; // whatever a is, we don't know
char* cp; // or something convertible to char*

// remember, this is not what actually gets generated
char* some_temporary_rvalue = reinterpret_cast<char*>(a);
some_temporary_rvalue = cp; // illegal, and senseless
```

With the reference, it becomes:

```
T a; // whatever a is, we don't know
char* cp; // or something convertible to char*

char*& a_treated_as_charptr = reinterpret_cast<char*&>(a);
a_treated_as_charptr = cp; // assigns a char* that is at &a
```

Comment: Why isn't `a_treated_as_charptr` a reference to a temporary?  Or is it the reference that *keeps* the temporary in scope?

Comment: And why do we have to cast `a` to a `*&`?  Why can't we just say:
`char*& a_treated_as_charptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(a);`?

Comment: STingRay: It's the reference in the cast that keeps `renterpret_cast` from creating an rvalue. With a reference, it says "treat this area of memory as this type"; without it, it says, "treat the value of this area in memory as this type" In fact, your second comment is illegal and will not compile. You'd be assigning a reference to a temporary variable. (Try the same process as in my post. You'd be saying `char*& a_treated_as_charptr = some_temporary_rvalue`)

Comment: I thought you can assign a temporary to a reference.

Comment: @STingRay: Only a `const&`. By the way, when it comes to references the term is "binding", since references can't technically be assigned (initializing also works.) :)

Comment: @GMan: ok, got it.  Thanks.  I just tried actually compiling the various permutations, and I see that you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

The interesting part, missing from the question is the type of `a`. I can just assume that it is some kind of pointer (it can actually be anything, but that assumption makes the discussion simpler).

```
T *a;
char* p = "Hello";
reinterpret_cast<char*&>(a) = p;
```

Under the assumption that `a` is in fact a pointer to another type, the result of the operation would be equivalent to:

```
T *a;
char *p = "Hello";
a = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p); // convert p to a T* and assign
```

The difference being that in the first version, the cast is being performed in the left hand side (LHS) of the assignment and thus must be a cast to a reference (lvalue), while in the second case the cast is performed in the right hand side (RHS) and thus a rvalue suffices and there is no need to cast to a reference.

Now, in the general case there are differences in the two casts. Reinterpret cast will just 'reinterpret' the memory as the type you tell it to. If the type of `a` and `char*` are of the same size (which under the assumption above holds, all pointers have the same size), then the two operations are the same and yield the same result.

On the other hand, if one type is bigger than the other then the two operations are not equivalent. If `sizeof(a) > sizeof(char*)` the first version will reinterpret the variable and overwrite only the first `sizeof(char*)` bytes of  `a` with the value of `p`. In the second case it will read `sizeof(a)` bytes from the memory location of `p` (causing undefined behavior, as it will read beyond the variable) and copy those bytes overwritting all the previous bytes in `a`.

The opposite goes if `sizeof(a) < sizeof(char*)` then the first version will overwrite beyond the allocated space for `a` causing undefined behavior, while the second will overwrite `a` with the first `sizeof(a)` bytes in `p`.